# Open only part of a GeoPackage layer with a certain geometry type in GeoPandas

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, geopackage, fiona

I have a [GeoPackage (743 MB, zipped)](https://inspire.lfrz.gv.at/009501/ds/inspire_schlaege_2019.gpkg.zip)  that has one layer, but two geometry types inside that layer (Point and Polygon). When I open the file in QGIS 3.10, QGIS presents a dialogue to me that lets me choose, which geometry type to add to the project.

[image: screenshot of QGIS vector layers add dialogue]

How can I achieve the same with GeoPandas? I don't see a way to specify the geometry type:

```py
gpd.read_file('inspire_schlaege_2019.gpkg', layer='inspire_schlaege_2019')
```

Comment: I am afraid that this kind of filtering is not supported in `fiona`, hence it is not supported in GeoPandas (as of 0.8.1). Since GeoDataFrame can contain mix geometry types, it never was an issue. I'd suggest opening an issue in fiona repository to suggest an enhancement.